# Login to another machine inside firewall

Tags: networking, server, firewall

we are a small company working with laptops in a shared office setting. We are inside a shared firewall managed by the company renting out office space, and we can not configure this in any way.

For normal laptop-work with connection to cloud services this works nicely, but we now have a on-prem build server (setup as a GitHub runner), and I would like to ssh to the build server. I guess I need some service to provide me with a (semi)static IP and some way of reaching it? I really have no clue?

J

Answer (score 0):

While you may not be able to change the behavior of your local firewall, at least knowing its rules can help. For example, if it only blocks certain ports on local IP addresses, you can get around this by using a non conventional port.

However, if your firewall blocks all traffic between local IP addresses like those guest Wi-Fi, then my intuition is:

1. Set up a cloud service (e.g., an OpenVPN server or an OpenSSH server) then use those to relay your traffic. **WARNING:** Considering you are setting this up for your company, this can have potential security risks if your cloud instance is attacked.
2. Create some physical connection or local wireless connection yourself, since your build server is on-prem.